# For symmetric, invertible $p$ x $p$ matrices $V$ and $A$, show that $(V^{-1} + A^{-1})^{-1}= A(V+A)^{-1}V = V(V+A)^{-1}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression, bayesian

I am trying to find an expression for E($\beta| \hat{\beta}$) in Bayesian Regression and showing that for symmetric, invertible $p$ x $p$ matrices $V$ and $A$,

$(V^{-1} + A^{-1})^{-1}= A(V+A)^{-1}V = V(V+A)^{-1}A$ will be useful.

My question isn't so much how to do the problem as it is what are useful properties of inverses that I will need to show this statement is true?

EDIT:

It is assumed that the sum is invertible.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you explicitly know that their sum is invertible? If you consider $V = -A = I$, it is easy to see that $V, A$ are both symmetric and invertible but their sum is not.

Comment: Yes, we do know that their sum is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the dimensions are finite a right-inverse is also a left-inverse. Now manually multiply $(V^{-1}+A^{-1})$ by what you think it's inverse is and it should be $I$.

$\begin{eqnarray}
V(V+A)^{-1}A(V^{-1}+A^{-1}) 
=&V(V+A)^{-1}(AV^{-1}+I)\\ 
=&V(V+A)^{-1}(AV^{-1}+I)VV^{-1}\\
=&V(V+A)^{-1}(A+V)V^{-1}\\
=&VV^{-1}\\=&I
\end{eqnarray}$

Similarly,

$\begin{eqnarray}
A(V+A)^{-1}V(V^{-1}+A^{-1}) 
=&A(V+A)^{-1}(I+VA^{-1})\\ 
=&A(V+A)^{-1}(I+VA^{-1})AA^{-1}\\
=&A(V+A)^{-1}(A+V)A^{-1}\\
=&AA^{-1}\\=&I
\end{eqnarray}$

Of course as mentioned in the comments this only works if everything if $A,V, (A+V)$ are all invertible :)